# Spring JDBCDAOSUPPORT for multiple datasources

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I need to support multiple datasources (sybase,oracle,mysql,cassandra etc) in my web application. I'm using spring framework in retrieving the datasource connections via the jndi which is configured in the tomcat container.

Now i need to know a programmatic way in spring to identif if the particular database technology is supported by Spring, so that I can use them in the project? Say for instance,cassandra (with spring3.0.7) is not supported but then I need to support it in my project..

If not please let me know like how do I switch between spring mode and normal jdbc mode based on the database.

Also I need to have the same bean id 'datasource' defined for all the datasources. jndiname property below should be replaced based on the input parameter to the program.i.e, i need to programmtically set this jndiname based on the parameter i get as an request.

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName">
            <value>{jndiname}</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

tech : java1.5, spring3.0.7 , tomcat6